# boost build on centos 6.5 failed bootstrap?

Tags: c++, boost

I bootstraped boost on a centos 6.5 cluster:

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=gcc --prefix=$HOME/opt 
./bjam -j12 toolset=gcc variant=release link=shared threading=multi address-model=64 cxxflags=-std=c++11 install
```

Which outputs:

```
32-bit                   : no  (cached)
    - 64-bit                   : no  (cached)
    - arm                      : no  (cached)
    - mips1                    : no  (cached)
    - power                    : no  (cached)
    - sparc                    : no  (cached)
    - x86                      : no  (cached)
    - combined                 : no  (cached)
    - lockfree boost::atomic_flag : no  (cached)
    - has_icu builds           : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - iconv (libc)             : no  (cached)
    - iconv (separate)         : no  (cached)
    - icu                      : no  (cached)
    - icu (lib64)              : no  (cached)
- Boost.Locale needs either iconv or ICU library to be built.
- Boost.Locale needs either iconv or ICU library to be built.
- Boost.Locale needs either iconv or ICU library to be built.
- Boost.Locale needs either iconv or ICU library to be built.
- Boost.Locale needs either iconv or ICU library to be built.
- Boost.Locale needs either iconv or ICU library to be built.
    - gcc visibility           : no  (cached)
    - long double support      : no  (cached)
```

I dont know why everything is no?
At least 64bit should be yes, how ever boost builds, but I dont know if that is a good sign that everything is no?
How can I fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few points here:

1) It could be just fine for everything to be "no", albeit some parts of boost won't get built.
2) Do you need to build boost?  Quite a lot is header only.
3) Notice the word "cached" after all of the results - this is not the first build you've run the build - if there have been build configuration changes since the last run, then delete the bin.v2 directory (where all the temporary build files get placed) and try again with a clean build.